# I want to use regular expression to search for all the lines that do not contain a specific string

Tags: regex

For example i want to exclude only those lines that do not contain xyz.

So in below three lines

```
xyz asfasffad
xsdadd xyz sdsdsdsd
asdgfdasf
```

It should match only the third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below regex to match the lines

```
^((?!xyz).)*$
```